# How can I split tightly coupled code in Java?

Tags: java, oop

So I've a class that is some kind of wrapper of a state machine for a multipart upload and it's database writes/reads. Everytime something is uploaded via REST basically the following happens

```
MyMultipartUpload mpu = multipartUploadFactory.create(...);
mpu.load(request.mpuID); //sets mutex lock
if (mpu.state != MpuState.UPLOAD) {
  throw...
}
mpu.addPart(hugeBinaryBlob); //mpu hold a persistency interface which allows saving to the database
...
```

Now I've a `mpu.process()` method that can be called when all parts arrived

```
MyMultipartUpload mpu = multipartUploadFactory.create(...);
mpu.load(request.mpuID); //sets mutex lock
if (mpu.state != MpuState.UPLOAD_COMPLETED) {
  throw...
}
mpu.process();
...
```

The `mpu.process()` method loads all parts one by one and first calls the private method `mpu.validate()`, does some data transformation, saves the new representation form and then triggers an async job.

```
// process()
List<Part> parts = persistency.loadPartsForId(mpuID);
for (Part part : parts) {
  var result = validate(part);
  if (result.containsErrors()) {
    setState(MpuState.ERROR);
    return;
  }

  var newForm = transformData(part);
  persistency.savePart(newForm);
}
```

Now my `MyMultipartUpload` coding has become super long (both `validate` and `transformData` have many LoC) and I'm wondering how I could refactor it into more classes (which would also help with unit tests).

What I thought about so far:

1. Have a `ValidationService` and `TransformationService` interface, where I can pass the part's content and do the validation / transformation. The service implementation is passed to the constructor of `MyMultipartUpload`. Saving in the database etc must still be done by the caller.
2. Have a `ProcessingService` interface, where I pass a whole `MyMultipartUpload` object. Here the service would have to do the saving of data and validation/transformation itself. This means I need to create a service with access to the persistency (same database tables MyMultipartUpload writes to via the persistency interface). This also means it must be ensured that the lock on the object is present while processing.

Is either of them a good approach?

Comment: If the code works, [codereview.se] or [softwareengineering.se] might be a better fit?

Comment: Go the other way around and say “how can I be certain that my code does what I want, and then write a test checking that. “ then write the final code when you’ve tested yhat each step works as intended

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is very good idea to split responsibilites between classes. The pros of this approach:

- your classes will follow Single Responsibility Principle of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).
- it becomes easier to write unit tests  and your code will be cleaner.

So, as your said your code would like this. This is an interface `IValidation`:

```
public interface IValidation
{
    bool Validate(Part part);
}
```

And an example of concrete classes:

```
class BarValidation : IValidation
{
    public bool Validate(Part part)
    {
        // your logic here for validation
        return true;
    }
}
```

And Processing:

```
public interface IProcessing
{
    void Process(Part part);
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class FooProcess : IProcessing
{
    public void Process(Part part)
    {
        
    }
}
```